# How to remove an inner shadow from one image view and set it on another after x-seconds

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

Hello everyone i'm making a artillery game for a school project and i'm stuck with something. On my help page i have a progress bar that fills up and returns to zero after 4 seconds(4 seconds to go from 0 to 100 and 4 seconds to go from 100 to 0). As you can see on the picture below i also have two images next to the progress bar. One arrow up and one arrow down image. My problem is that i want to light up the arrow up image for 4 seconds and then switch the highlight over to the arrow down image for 4 seconds and then the other way around. I also want to repeat this action until the help page is closed. Simply put i want to simulate what happens to the 'power bar' if you press the arrow up or arrow down key. I tried using this code:

```
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("Now:" + now);
            long end = now + 4000;
            System.out.println("End:" + end);
            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
            view.getSecondaryStage().show();
            //view.getSecondaryStage().showAndWait();

            if (System.currentTimeMillis() > end && !view.getKeyUP().getEffect().equals(null) ){
                    view.getKeyUP().setEffect(null);
                    view.getKeyDown().setEffect(view.getHighLight());

            }
            else if (System.currentTimeMillis() > end && !view.getKeyDown().getEffect().equals(null)){
                    view.getKeyDown().setEffect(null);
                    view.getKeyUP().setEffect(view.getHighLight());

            }
            else {
                System.out.println("neither");
            }
        }
```

Does anyone know what i did wrong? Thanks in advance!

[Here you can see the help screen i'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkebB.png)

Comment: Unless it somehow took 4 seconds to execute the first 6 lines of code, how could `System.getCurrentTimeMills() > end` ever be true?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to solve this. Unfortunately you didn't provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Among the solutions to solve this are e. g. transitions like a [SequentialTransition](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/SequentialTransition.html), a [PauseTransition](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/PauseTransition.html), a custom [transition](https://rterp.wordpress.com/2015/09/01/creating-custom-animated-transitions-with-javafx/), etc. Or you could use an [AnimationTimer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/package-summary.html) for that.